# Memory management for types in complex languages

Tags: c++, memory-management, compiler-construction

I've come across a slight problem for writing memory management with regard to the internal representation of types in a compiler for statically typed, complex languages. Consider a simple snippet in C++ which easily demonstrates a type that refers to itself.

```
class X {
    void f(const X&) {}
};
```

Types can have nearly infinitely complex relationships to each other. So, as a compiler process, how do you make sure that they are properly collected?

So far, I've decided that garbage collection might be the right way to go, which I wouldn't be too happy with because I want to write the compiler in C++, or alternatively, just leave them and never collect them for the life of the compile phase for which they are needed (which has a very fixed lifetime) and then collect them all afterwards. The problem with that is that if you had a lot of complex types, you could lose a lot of memory that way.

Comment: What objects are you concerned with, exactly? Tokens? AST nodes? How does this relate to statically  typed, “complex” (?) languages?

Comment: Common solution is to add several passes to your compiler. This is the easiest way to do it. First pass just resolves these names and links them, and then in the next pass it can be used. Depending on language, you might need several passes to get everything available correctly.

Comment: @Konrad: The internal representation of a type, would probably be something like a class named Type. @tp1: That is for parsing and resolving symbols.. not managing the memory of the objects those symbols correspond to.

Comment: What is your definition of *a lot of memory*, what is the target of your compiler? You can fit a huge amount of memory representations of *complex* types in a few megs of memory. I would go for the simple thing: keep them around for the whole phase, and only if that proves itself to be a problem work on optimizing it.

Comment: @David: Well, keeping around type objects that are no longer necessary is quite the definition of a leak. I prefer not to design leaks into my program. I guess you might be right about the scale- post it as an answer and I may accept it.

Comment: @deadmg: the memory dependencies are no different from name dependencies. In both cases, the links need to be available completely before you can start following the links and relying that they are all there. (note that this also happens in things like the web html pages. The whole page needs to be available before browser allows following any of the links)

Comment: @DeadMG: Is it really a leak? Is there an instant where you can guarantee that it will not be needed at any later time? One of the simple answers is yes, there is: right after this phase completes, and if you clear the memory at that instant in time, you should be fine. Again, as with most other things, unless it is a problem later on, there is no point in trying to solve it upfront, with the additional benefit that once you complete coding that phase in the simple way, you will have a greater knowledge of the problem, and then if you need to optimize you will have more information to use.

Comment: @DeadMG: Unless you are dealing with huge amounts of autogenerated code, the memory you need for the _types_ is going to be tiny compared to your (decorated) AST. Keeping the types around is usually no problem, and is useful for diagnostics as well. You should definitely try to get your compiler running on some real-world test cases to get a feeling where the memory usage goes.

Answer (score 1):

Memory management is easy, just have some table type-name -> type-descriptor for each declaration scopes. Types are uniquely identified by name, no matter how complex the nesting is. Even a recursive type is still only a single type. As tp1 says correctly, you typically perform multiple passes to fill in all blanks. For instance, you might check that a type name is known in the first pass and then compute all links, later on, you compute the type.

Keep in mind that languages like C don't have a really complex type system -- even though they have pointers (which allow for recursive types), there is not much type computation going on.

Comment: In my language then many types will have no name and no place in the global namespace.

Comment: @DeadMG: You could just generate a unique name e.g. `#AnonStruct15`. There is no way to refer to the anonymous type by name anyway, so it should be safe.

Comment: @DeadMG if you have <code>void main() { List&lt;string&gt; MyList = new List&lt;string&gt;()</code>, the "MyList" variable is an internal anonymous type, maybe with an automatic generated id. by your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove the cycles from the dependency graph by using separate objects to represent *declarations* and *definitions*. Assuming a type system similar to C++, you will then have a hierarchical dependency:

- Function *definitions* depend on type *definitions* and function *declarations*
- Type *definitions* depend on function and type *declarations* (and *definitions* of contained types)
- Function *declarations* depend on type *declarations*

In your example, the dependency graph is `f_def -> X_def -> f_decl -> X_decl`.

With no cycles in the graph, you can manage objects using simple reference counting.

Comment: The trouble is the second line. Type definitions depend on type definitions. `class X { std::vector<X> my_x_vector; };`

Comment: @DeadMG: Does it depend on the definition of `X` or on the declaration of `X`?

Comment: If the template instantiation needs the definition of `X`, then the code is ill-formed, since `X` is incomplete at that point. `vector` only requires a declaration of `X`, so there is no problem.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I'm pretty sure that `vector` requires a definition, since it calls member functions like the copy constructor and destructor, and that X is fully defined in it's scope.

Comment: @DeadMG: its member functions require the definition, but they aren't instantiated until they are needed. The class definition only needs a declaration, since it doesn't contain any objects of type `X`. If it did need a definition, then your example code wouldn't compile, since `X` is incomplete when `vector<X>` is instantiated.

Comment: So the dependencies are `V<X>::f_def -> X_def -> V<X>_def -> V<X>::f_decl -> X_decl` (where `f` is some member function of `V<X>`), still with no cycles.